# How to export SCCM 2012 R2 Aplication in c# or VB.net?

Tags: sccm

I want to export an application (not a package) for our SCCM test server to our production server.

I know i can do it with the powershell cmdlet 'Export-CMApplication' but i need to use 2 different credentials to access the test server and the production server and i can't pass the credential to this cmdlet.

I think i can make it with the dll 'Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement' but i don't find any relevant information as to how to do it.

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not look at the VB or C# cmdlet yet, sure there is a way.
But just sticking to Powershell and command line, looking [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/04/28/how-can-i-use-the-runas-command-to-run-a-script-under-alternate-user-credentials/).
Did you try?

```
runas /profile /user:otherdomain\testuser “powershell.exe \”C:\somepath\powershell\script.ps1”\”
```

Can also be unattended, but that is not very secure.

Comment: Good idea !

Only problem is that the test and production server are not in the same network Windows domain. So i can't use the runas command.

I need to connect to the server using credential by parsing the credential to the command line or someting like that.

Comment: @PhilNic:
Yes, that is my last comment.
You could make it unattended, but this could require to put passwords plain text in a script.